# Thread contention on java.io.PrintStream

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using Java Mission Control to profile my application for performance issues. JMC has highlighted java.io.PrintStream under Thread Contention and Lock Instances sections.

Why am I facing thread contention issues for JDK package?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your application is producing a lot of output to stdout or stderr from several threads concurrently (`System.out` and `System.err` are `PrintStream`s). Writes and flushes on a `PrintStream` cannot be processed in parallel, they are all synchronized, so you're facing contention.

Comment: Andrew, I took a look at the stack trace and it came from the 3rd party framework methods calls which I am using. I would like to disable System.out but I do not have the source codes.

Comment: Third party frameworks likely use some logging frameworks like log4j or others. You can configure logging in your app and assign `WARN` or `ERROR` level for third-patry java packages to reduce excessive logging.

Comment: @youcanlearnanything, doest the library use `System.out` directly? Or maybe it emits messages to some logging framework that can be configured?

Comment: How do I tell if I can pipe the messages to a logging framework? I don't see codes like Logger.getLogger() in the decompiled classes

Comment: If you see direct calls to `System.out.println()` and don't see loggers, it means that the library doesn't use logging frameworks. If contention is a real problem for you app, and you want to do something about it, you can substitute the `System.out` for your own implementation of `PrintStream` that can use some techniques to decrease contention: `System.setOut(myPrintStream)`.

Comment: I am running a web application, I should override the System.out using a context listener class on start up?

Comment: Actually, app servers usually substitute stdout themselves and redirect all the output into a log file. So, you must be very careful with what you're going to do and understand all the consequences, especially if your application is not the only one in the web container. It would be good if you could save the reference to the `System.out`, substitute it and only filter out the messages from the problem library, sending all the rest to the saved `PrintStream`. It would be reasonable to do the substitution on the app startup and put the original stdout stream back when your app stops.

Comment: Does redirecting the output to a log file works since the contention is on the synchronization of the print screen. I am using WebLogic as my application server, and I am sure it can redirect stout to log files.

Comment: Synchronization is implemented at the `PrintStream` level, not at the level of underlying `OutputStream`. Since messages must be printed line-by-line, without interruption, you won't be able to get rid of synchronization completely. You only can reduce the number of concurrent calls to the underlying `PrintStream` (by filtering out some messages) if you want to preserve correct output. It doesn't depend on the final destination, be it a terminal, a file, a TCP socket or something else.

Comment: Andrew, I have added the dummy printscreen and ran JMC again. The thread contention no longer exists. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I am thinking of implementing a dummy printstream to use log4j, which to use log.debug(), this will allow me to turn it on in my test environment, and off for my prod environment. Does it sounds like a better approach?

Comment: I'm glad the problem has been tracked down to the real cause. Technically, the approach with a logger should work. The best solution would be to separate the messages of the library from others and use this approach to them alone. But if it's impossible, you can propagate the approach to all the messages. Just remember that the app server can write something useful to the stdout too.

Comment: Andrew, I don't quite get you. how do I separate the messages of the library from the rest of my application?

Comment: Sorry for vagueness. I'm speaking generally. I can't tell how to separate them because I've never seen them. Maybe, there's some marker in those messages, maybe they have a special format that can be identified programmatically, maybe they all the same or it's only a small number of predefined messages that can be easily identified. But maybe there're no way to separate them. I just said that if it's possible, it's better to do that. If not, then there's nothing you can do about it and skipping all the messages is the way to go.

Comment: For learning purposes, can you explain how does it require synchronise? I went to take a look on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out and it didnt had the sychronized keyword on the method itself.

Comment: `System.out` is not a method, it's a public static field of type `PrintStream`. If you open the source code of `PrintStream` and look at the `println(...)` methods, you'll see synchronized blocks.

Comment: Thank you Andrew! I will take a look at it.